# Facebook - get user Access Token via Cronjob

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

is it possible to get an valid access token for an user via a cronjob?
i want to create an app that parse every night all posts from the user and check if there are some special chars.

with the app access key i have only access to the public posts from the user.. with the user access token i can access also private posts

but the user access token expires

is it possible to refresh the user token with an cronjob? that means the cronjob may have to refresh 100 user access tokens and i dont have the user du open the authorization dialog because its called on a server via cronjob

I'am using php for the facebook api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible, it even say that explicitly in the official [Removal of offline_access Permission](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/) post:

> The user must access your application before you're able to get a
>   valid "authorization code" to be able to make the server-side OAuth
>   call again. Apps will not be able to setup a **background/cron job** that
>   tries to automatically extend the expiration time, because the
>   "authorization code" is short-lived and will have expired.

With that said, when you get an access token from a [Server-Side authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/) flow, the token you get should last for a month, if you persist it then you can then use it for that month.

After that month is over, and if the user hasn't re-engaged your app then the access token will be expired and you'll have to pass on that user.

Comment: thanks that helps a lot. Do you know what i have to do to get an access token that is valid for a month? do i just have to use the server-side authentication or do i have to take care of something else?

Comment: As it says in the link I gave you in the answer: *"If the access_token is generated from a server-side OAuth call, the resulting access_token will have the longer expiration time"*, and so that will suffice, also you can use the client side auth and then use the new endpoint discussed in that link as well, in order to extend the access token. It's easier to just use the server side flow in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the facebook jdk you can use: `$token = $facebook->getAccessToken();` 
then, save `$token` into database for use by cronjob

```
    $args = array(
                 'access_token'  => $page_info['access_token'], //Offline Access Token From Database
                 'message'       => $_POST['description'],
                 'link'          =>$_POST['link'],
                 'picture'       =>$_POST['image'],
                 'name'          =>$_POST['title']
                 );
    $post_id = $facebook->api("/$page_id/feed","post",$args);
```

with `$page_id` is id of fanpage or

```
$post_id = $facebook->api("/me/feed","post",$args);
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is once the token expire, your job is going to fail unless human intervention to replace the token.